# Python Arrays of Tuples

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy, tuples

I'm trying to write a for loop in python to create an array of tuples that should look like

```
Output = [(0.0,C[0]),(0.0,C[1]),(0.0,C[2]), .... , (0.0,C[n-1])]
```

where `C` is an array of some other numbers.

If I try (something that would work with matlab)

```
for n in xrange(0,N):
    Output[n]=numpy.asarray( [0.0,C[n]] )
```

then I get the error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
output = np.zeros((N, 2), dtype='float')
output[:, 1] = C[:N]
```

BTW, an "array of tuples" doesn't make much sense to me. If you mean an object array (maybe a cell array in matlab?) I'd recommend using a list instead of an array.

Answer (score 4):

```
numpy.array([(0.0, C[x]) for x in range(n)])
```

Comment: And if `n` is the length of the array `C`, just `numpy.array([(0.0, c) for c in C])`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Structured arrays (aka “Record arrays”): http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html

You can define such things:

```
>>> x = np.zeros((2,),dtype=('i4,f4,a10'))
>>> x[:] = [(1,2.,'Hello'),(2,3.,"World")]
>>> x
array([(1, 2.0, 'Hello'), (2, 3.0, 'World')],
     dtype=[('f0', '>i4'), ('f1', '>f4'), ('f2', '|S10')])
```